# In the given example for finding the value " pp-p" on line 5 why the values are divided by 2 in the explanation?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>  
void main ()  
{  
    int a[10] = {100, 206, 300, 409, 509, 601}; //Line 1 array declared
    int *p[] = {a, a+1, a+2, a+3, a+4, a+5}; //Line 2  pointer to the array
    int **pp = p; //Line 3  double pointer initialized
    pp++; // Line 4  double pointer incremented
    printf("%d %d %d\n",pp-p,*pp - a,**pp); // Line 5  
    *pp++; // Line 6  
    printf("%d %d %d\n",pp-p,*pp - a,**pp); // Line 7  
    ++*pp; // Line 8  
    printf("%d %d %d\n",pp-p,*pp - a,**pp); // Line 9  
    ++**pp; // Line 10   
    printf("%d %d %d\n",pp-p,*pp - a,**pp); // Line 11  
}
```

/* Line number 5 contains an expression which prints three values, i.e., pp - p, *pp - a, **pp. Let's calculate them each one of them.

```
pp = 302, p = 300 => pp-p = (302-300)/2 => pp-p = 1, i.e., 1 will be printed.
pp = 302, *pp = 202, a = 200 => *pp - a = 202 - 200 = 2/2 = 1, i.e., 1 will be printed.
pp = 302, *pp = 202, *(*pp) = 206, i.e., 206 will be printed. */
```

Comment: Some issues unrelated to your question: `main` should have return type `int`. Line 2 is Array of pointers, not pointer to array.

Comment: i was expecting  this ->pp-p = (302-300)=2  and not this--> pp-p = (302-300)/2=1

Comment: Where do you get your addresses `pp=302, p=300`?

Comment: What have you learned about pointer arithmetics so far? Be aware that `pp=p; pp++;` means same as `pp=p+1`. Therefore `pp-p = p+1-p = 1`

Comment: Please provide the real output of the program.

Comment: addresses of all variables are imaginary.

Comment: Output:

1 1 206
2 2 300
2 3 409
2 3 410

Comment: imaginary address: array a :  200,202,204....,212.    array of  pointers p[ ]  : 300,302,304......,312.

Comment: You can find this question here --->  https://www.javatpoint.com/c-pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: OK, now it starts making sense. The numbers are not really useful without that image. That's just fundamental pointer arithmetics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see there is basic pointer arithmetics. That's just how adding and substracting to and from pointers works in C.

Let's start with an array:

```
int a[10] = {100, 206, 300, 409, 509, 601};
```

You can access these elements using array syntax:

```
a[0] = xy;
a[2] = 1;
```

This is identical to the following syntax using pointer arithmetics:

```
*a = xy;
*(a+2) = 1;
```

You can see that you can add an index `n` to access the `n`th element of your array. For obvious reasons this does not just add the index to the address. Each element has a certain size.
Therefore the rules for arithmetics tell us that the address is adjusted by `n` bytes, but by `n` data objects.
How many bytes we need to add/subtract is derived from the size of each object.
For `a` it is `sizeof(int)`, for `p` it is `sizeof(int*)`.

The result of adding a number to a pointer is a pointer again. Using normal math rules, you can subtract 2 pointers (if they point into the same array) and get a number which is (again) the number of objects, not the number of bytes.

This means `&a[2] - &a[1] == 1`. This is true for any size.

Now we look at your code:

```
int **pp = p;
pp++;
```

This is same as `pp = &p[1]` which is `pp=p+1`. And hence `*pp==p[1]==a+1`

Now print it:

```
printf("%d %d %d\n",pp-p,*pp - a,**pp);
```

Apply the rules from above:

```
pp-p == p+1 - p == 1
*pp-a == p[1] - a == a+1 - 1 == 1
**pp == *p[1] == *(a+1) == a[1] = 206
```

==> `1 1 206`

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped me a lot.